# Converting MPG to KPL using alchemist gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the alchemist gem: https://github.com/halogenandtoast/alchemist

`10.miles.per.gallons.to.kilometers.per.liters.value`

Does not work. Any ideas how to convert mpg to kpl using alchemist?

`10.miles.to.kilometers.value` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the gem doesn't support this due not having a good way to express the syntax. I'll ponder on this and see if I can come up with a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about`10.miles.to.kilometers.per.(1.gallons.to.liters).value` ?